# how to convert this date:2011-02-10T07:18:04+0000 to unix timestamp in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, timestamp, facebook-graph-api

Im using Facebook Graph Api , and the in the paging parameter it returns this string after i decode it from **2011-02-10T06%3A52%3A02%2B0000**  to   **2011-02-10T07:18:04+0000**
and now i like to convert the decode string to unix time stamp in Qt or plain c++

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use the `QDate::fromString()` method to create a `QDate` from a formatted string.</strike>

Edit: Correction use `QDateTime` instead as that provides the `toTime_t()` method to get the timestamp:

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(formatted, formatString);
long timestamp = dt.toTime_t();
```

I'll let you work out what `formatString` should look like.

Comment: Addition: If that percent-encoding is actually part of the string and not an artifact of the string: Pass it through QByteArray::fromPercentEncoding() to get rid of it.

Comment: this is what i did to get the real date Human readable format

Comment: and how can i get this formated QDate and convert it to timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard function [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) should be enough. (But, as per comment below, it's less portable than the Qt-based solution)

Comment: `strptime()` doesn't exist under Windows so isn't really in the spirit of Qt's cross platform awesomeness.